# getting classcast exception while converting date from string type to date data type

Tags: java, hibernate, date, criteria

I am getting the date (SettlementDate) in form of string in a method parameter as  shown in the below method

```
   public List<abc> eee(Long Id,
                String sfsdf, boolean dfds,
                 String SettlementDate,
                ) {
```

now I  am applying criteria as shown below but in pojo to which I am applying criteria IN THAT POJO THAT FIELD (SettlementDate)  is of Date type  as shown below

```
class ddd
{
private Date settlementDate;
}
```

below is the criteria implemetation

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(ddd.class);
query.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", Id));
query.add(Restrictions.eq("sfsdf", sfsdf));
query.add(Restrictions.eq("settlementDate", SettlementDate );
```

ultimately in database i want to store the date in this format 22.07.2016 00:00:00

now please advise how how do i set this value in criteria as rite now I am getting class cast exception in the below line

```
query.add(Restrictions.eq("settlementDate", SettlementDate );
```

which clearly proves that date of string type is not converted in date format ( 22.07.2016 00:00:00)
folks , if I have to use simple date format then please advise how to use that in this situation ,Thanks

Comment: **A date does not have a format.**

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis date i want to store in this format 22.07.2016 00:00:00

Comment: **A date does not have a format.** You're not storing a format, you're storing a date.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis agree can you please advise , how can I convert the date from string type to date data type

Comment: You only have to use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @kai Thanks can you please advise how to that request you tp please post it so that I can grasp thanks

Comment: This question is currently not possible to answer. You need to parse the string to convert it to a proper Date object. To do that you need to know what the string looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want convert a date string to a date. You can try this:

```
query.add(Restrictions.eq("settlementDate", new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(SettlementDate)));
```

Some other remarks:

- When storing a date in a db, you should use a Date or DateTime format, or maybe a Number containing the millisecs, but definately not a String
- Java classes should start with a capital
- Variable and parameter names should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: @Fortega i tnk you have miss one bracket as it is giving compliation errors